# Multi file upload with carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, carrierwave

I recently watched Ryan`s episode 381 about Jquery file upload and now I wonder how to add support of nested forms. Say I have product and products has many images. What should I do to add this without polymorphic association?

Comment: Not yet. But I found an example https://github.com/n0ne/Rails-Carrierwave-jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/app/controllers/galleries_controller.rb, maybe it will help.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear exactly what you're asking, or what polymorphic associations have to do with this, but I think I may have had the same problem (though I used plupload instead)

My solution was to generate a short random string (I used `SecureRandom.hex(6)`, but I'm sure there are other ways to do it) and include it in my product form view. I included it as a hidden field in the form and also as a javascript variable.

```
<%= javascript_tag do %>
  window.tmp_id = "<%= tmp_id %>"
<% end %>
```

In my plupload config I added this variable to the POST request that uploads the image. For jQuery file upload I think you'd want something like this:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
  url: '/path/to/upload/handler',
  formData: { tmp_id: tmp_id }
});
```

So in the controller that handles the file uploads, I just take the file and stick it in a temporary directory named using the tmp_id passed in via params.

When the controller receives the form submission it uses the model to check for the existence of the temp directory and processes the images found inside there, creating new records for each one that are tied to the newly created Product.

May not be exactly what you're looking for but thought it might give you some ideas.